# Converting SecureString stored in text file back to readable string

Tags: .net, string, powershell, security, securestring

I'm having trouble converting a previously stored SecureString back to it's original string.  I'm doing this because I believe there may have been a typo when originally entering the password.

The SecureString was initially created and stored in a text file using the following:

```
$SecurePassword = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString
$SecurePassword | ConvertFrom-SecureString > C:\TEMP\TEST_Secure.txt
```

For my application of choice (Veeam backup) I read the file containing the encrypted password and fed it back in to the application

```
$SecurePasswordPath = "C:\TEMP\TEST_Secure.txt"
$EncryptionKey = cat $SecurePasswordPath | ConvertTo-SecureString
```

The Veeam backup script is actually reading it as follows:

```
$EncryptionKey = Add-VBREncryptionKey -Password (cat $SecurePasswordPath | ConvertTo-SecureString)
```

I've tried the following to try and recover the key:

```
$new1 = cat $SecurePasswordPath | ConvertTo-SecureString

$Ptr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToCoTaskMemUnicode($new1)
$result = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringUni($Ptr)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeCoTaskMemUnicode($Ptr)
```

The result of that usually is a blank field.

I've also tried the more recommended method:

```
$new1 = cat $SecurePasswordPath | ConvertTo-SecureString
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($new1))
```

Each of these results in nothing being returned at all really.

My fear is that I did not follow proper syntax when creating and will not be able to recover the original key, thus not able to recover my backups.

Getting desperate here!  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Was the SecureString originally encrypted on the same computer that you are trying to decrypt it on?

Comment: Yes.  Same machine.

Comment: And as the same user account?

Comment: Different user account likely was initially used.  My problem is, i can step through the above steps and it still doesn't produce the desired output.  So, I can re-create a new SecureString text file on same machine, same user, and run through the two methods to try and retrieve password and it still fails with the same results.  This is why I'm questioning whether or not I set it up properly.

Comment: `ConvertTo-SecureString` only works on the same computer and the same user account if you use DPAPI (i.e., no `-Key` or `-SecureKey` parameter).

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to prompt for a `SecureString` and write it to a text file as an encrypted standard string:

```
Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString | 
  ConvertFrom-SecureString |
  Out-File "D:\Path\EncryptedStandardString.txt"
```

To reverse this and obtain a `SecureString` object:

```
$secureString = Get-Content "D:\Path\EncryptedStandardString.txt" |
  ConvertTo-SecureString
```

If you want to use AES rather than DPAPI, you need to also provide the `-Key` or `-SecureKey` parameter to the `ConvertFrom-SecureString` and `ConvertTo-SecureString` cmdlets.

If you want to decrypt a `SecureString` into a `String` object, you can use the following function:

```
function ConvertTo-String {
  param(
    [Security.SecureString]
    $secureString
  )
  try {
    $bstr = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secureString)
    [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($bstr)
  }
  finally {
    if ( $bstr -ne [IntPtr]::Zero ) {
      [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($bstr)
    }
  }
}
```

**Caution:** If you use this function, you are bypassing the protections that `SecureString` objects provide.

Comment: Is this significantly different from using `Export-CliXml`, which stores credentials on disk using the DPAPI but without having to do any ConvertTo or ConvertFrom?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - no - the convenience of `Export-CliXml` is that it stores a `PSCredential` object and not just a `SecureString`. However it doesn't support AES.

Comment: `[System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new('', $secureString).Password` is much cleaner than `SecureStringToBSTR`

Comment: 1) At the time I was focused on the `SecureString` object, and the `NetworkCredential` object has a username parameter that would be ignored in this context. (The point here was to show how to get a `SecureString` object's plain-text equivalent.) 2) IIRC, the `new` method for type accelerators didn't show up until PS v3, and when I wrote this answer backward compatibility with PS v2 was still a issue (at least for me).